# XSLT 1.0 Test if node passed with call-template is last of parent's children

Tags: xslt

```
<TEI>
    <text id="R">
    <text id="E">
    <text id="D">
</TEI>
```

If I call a template and pass the node `<text id="E">` in as a parameter, what test expression, executed inside the template, will test whether text E is the last of `<TEI>`'s children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I call a template and pass the node `<text id="E">` in as a
>   parameter, what test expression, executed inside the template, will
>   test whether text E is the last of `<TEI>`'s children?

**I assume that by `<TEI>`'s children you mean `<TEI>`'s *element*-children**.

If so, use:

```
not($p/following-sibling::*[1])
```

the above may be more efficient (in case the XPath optimizer isn't too smart) than the equivalent:

```
not($p/following-sibling::*)
```

**In case that by by `<TEI>`'s children you mean `<TEI>`'s any-node-type** (text, comment, PI and element)-**children, then use this XPath expression**:

```
not($p/following-sibling::node()[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the name of the parameter in your template was **element**, you could achieve this by checking if there are any following siblings of the element

```
<xsl:value-of select="not($element/following-sibling::*)" />
```

So, given the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/TEI">
    <xsl:call-template name="text">
      <xsl:with-param name="element" select="text[@id='E']"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="text">
    <xsl:param name="element" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($element/following-sibling::*)">Last</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>Not Last</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<TEI> 
    <text id="R" /> 
    <text id="E" /> 
    <text id="D" /> 
</TEI>
```

The following is output

```
Not Last
```

Change the parameter to the **E** element, the the following it output instead

```
Last
```

However, if possible, it might be better to avoid the use of **call-template** with a parameter. A better design pattern would be to make use of **apply-templates** here

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/TEI">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text[@id='D']" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text[following-sibling::*]">
    <xsl:text>Not Last</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:text>Last</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should also yield the same results